# Is human thought a Continuum?

Tags: metaphilosophy

Plato probably would not have existed had it not been for Pythagoras and Socrates.  Augustine would not have produced his writings had it not been for Plotinus and Aristotle. Einstein would not have produced relativity had it not been for Newton and so on. Is it correct to consider human thought in its entirety as a continuous functions whose points represent the great thinkers of history?  Were there philosophers who examined this view?

Comment: "As an integral whose derivatives represent the great thinkers of history" What do you mean by this? Are you using the mathematical definitions of those words?

Comment: Not quite the mathematical definitions, more like a poetic license. If it doesnt fit, i am gonna edit the question.

Comment: Yeah as written, that sentence makes as much sense as "colourless green ideas sleep furiously".

Comment: Ok, done. Is it better?

Comment: Do you literally mean "continuous" in the mathematical sense of varying in a way that's infinitely divisible, or do you just mean it in the metaphorical sense that each new idea builds on and depends on what came before? Anyone in the [historicist](https://www.philosophybasics.com/branch_historicism.html) tradition of Hegel might fit into the latter, and you also might be interested in something like [The Sociology of Philosophies](http://socresonline.org.uk/4/3/collins.html).

Comment: I mean continuum, in the mathematical sense.

Comment: So like if future physics theories showed that time is discrete and there are no changes that take less than one [Planck time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time) (about 5 x 10^-44 seconds), are you saying that would be enough to invalidate what you meant when you said that human thought being a continuum, because in that case changes in human philosophical thought would not be infinitely divisible?

Comment: I would say no: human thought cannot even remotely be affected by the structure of space-time on the Planck scale. When you think, the flow of your thought is a continuous cascade, you don't perceive your thoughts in discrete packets. My question is if this perceived continuous goes beyound individuals.

Comment: In that case you aren't describing a continuum in the [mathematical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function), since for a function to be continuous it must be possible to get arbitrarily small changes in the output variable(s) (which I guess would represent aspects of our philosophical ideas) by picking smaller and smaller increments of the input variable (in this case time), with no lower limit on how small the increments can be. The fact that we don't *perceive* discrete increments of our own thought doesn't mean there aren't any, after all neurons fire in discrete pulses.

Comment: I said mathematical sense because the mathematical continuum is the one that come closer to what i have in mind but i dont think you must take it literally. Also contraddictions arise even in the other way: if we say that human thought is discrete, how you define this discreteness? Where did discreteness in thought arise? Is it between thoughts, between thinkers, between century, what's the interval? And even if you choose one, who is to say that it is correct? When speaking about thought i think is much more difficult to think of it as discrete.

Comment: If you don't mean it in the literal mathematical sense, but you also don't just mean that every new thought builds on what has come before & wouldn't be possible without it (that's what I thought you meant based on comments about various thinkers' ideas depending on prior thinkers, but when I suggested that interpretation in my first comment you said you meant it in something closer to the mathematical sense), maybe you could try to explain a little more what you do mean? As for thought in general, I see no contradiction in using the time of a neuron firing as a lower bound for changes.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I used the definition "Mathematical Continuum" because it is what I have in mind when I think of thinking (small recursion here). Thought is perceived by the individual as continuous, If for physics it's not, it doesn't matter. 
My question, in essence, was whether this perception of continuity of thought could be extended between individuals. Furthermore, respectfully, I find myself in disagreement on one point: I do not consider the firing of a neuron as the lover bound of thought in the same way that I do not believe that an atom is a person's lower bound.

Comment: No. We have finitely many neurons hence finitely many possible paths through our brain hence finitely many thoughts. Finitely many people have lived. There's a finite upper limit to how many thoughts have ever been thought, even privately; let alone written down.

Comment: *"I do not consider the firing of a neuron as the lover bound of thought in the same way that I do not believe that an atom is a person's lower bound."* By "lower bound" I mean that we don't know the shortest period in which one can generate a new meaningful thought, but it's probably safe to say that the period can't be shorter than the time for a single neuron to fire. So I guess the analogy would be that we don't know how small an organism can be and still be reasonably considered a "person", but it's safe to say it can't be smaller than an atom. You don't agree those are safe assumptions?

Comment: In light of the extended comments, perhaps you could revise and clarify the question.

Comment: Have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Kuhn#The_Structure_of_Scientific_Revolutions

Answer (score 0):

It's not even faintly tenable. There has definitely been a reaction back agaibst the 'great man theory of history', there has no doubt been too nuch focus in the past 9n unique individuals vs global trends. Human population, and kniwledge, have increased gigantically, also shifting tge focus away from individuals. But look at someone like Elon Musk, who has catalysed the new space race, altering the rate at which Mars and the solar system will be explored relative to other technologies.

Hegel certaintly depersonalised history, seeing humans as agents of the dialectic. But consider the analogy to evolution: there are niches, there is competition, and real dynamics can be used to explain the outcomes. But, each time the system is run, it is not deterministic - it is a stochastic process. The same with the development 8f ideas. We are not simply exploring a space, we a creating a space of ideas, if culture, which informs how we interact.